# What does "It dopes it really really well. Dope even" mean?

Tags: meaning, errors

Recently I came across a stackoverflow comment for a post. It goes something like this.

> Dojo has an UpgradeBar that dopes
>   this:
>
> Blah Blah Blah

and then somebody commented the post

> It dopes it really really well. Dope
>   even

I know dope is to take drug and thus may be he is meaning it as *relaxed*. Now i am a bit confused what did this guy meant. because in the end there is "Dope even". did he mean it **relaxes him** or **it sucks**?

will "*something* **even**" make a context *negative*?

Full Context : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188667/stackoverflow-welcome-bar/5197218#5197218

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without seeing any further context, I have to presume that the original post was a typo of "dopes" for "does", and the comment was simply mocking the typo.  (the "dope even" part is using "dope" in its adjectival form, meaning "awesome".)

Edit: having seen the context provided, I'm quite certain that it was a typo and that the comment was poking fun at the typo.

Comment: This is the context. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188667/stackoverflow-welcome-bar/5197218#5197218

Comment: I know "dope" can mean "awesome", but what does "dope even" (or "awesome even") mean?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Suppose somebody says "I shaved my bear" (instead of "I shaved my beard"); who listened could reply with "beard even", or "beard, even". It's just a way to correct what somebody else said.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Yes, that also I know… but with that interpretation, here "dope" is being corrected with "dope", which doesn't make sense. Maybe the commenter meant to write "Does, even" and made a mistake in the correction? :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Who wrote the sentence reported by the OP is making fun of his own typo. Saying "dope even", he is making other notice he wrote _dopes_ instead of _does_; who reads could have mentally replaced "it dopes" with "it does", and could not have noticed the typo.

Comment: @Shreevatsar:  "it does it really really well.  Dope, even." -> "it does it so well that you could even say it's awesome."  Throw in "dopes" for "does" to poke a little fun at the typo and you're all set.